# Get latest upload from channel (and not the latest "what to watch next" video)

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Before you close this as a duplicate, please read the whole question, because I am quite certain that it isn't.

---

For a website I am writing, I want to get the latest video uploaded to a Youtube channel. This is the code I am currently using:

```
$uploadid = json_decode(
    file_get_contents(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=" . $youtube_username . "&key=" . $youtube_apikey), 
        true
    )["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"];

$latest_videoid = json_decode(
    file_get_contents(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=1&playlistId=" . $uploadid . "&key=" . $youtube_apikey), 
        true
    )["items"][0]["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"];
```

as referenced in the [Channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) and the [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) documentation.

But rather than always returning the first entry in the uploads playlist, it consistently (on some channels) returns a "What to watch next" video first, which is then (usually) followed by the most recent upload in the second entry.

I know a band-aid solution would be just to grab the first 2-5 videos, and then pick out the one with the most recent date, but this would require a lot more request than necessary, and may also still not be the latest video depending on how it is ordered.

So how do I get the playlist id for a channels' upload playlist, rather than a semi-"what to watch next" playlist?

Also, none of these users are authenticating themselves, and that's the way I want to keep it.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.